# VBA Userform to save textbox.Value to excel worksheet when name is selected in combobox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I apologize in advance for posting the same question, but I don't know how else to add additional code example.  If there is a way to add additional code to a previous question, please advise. Basically, I am trying to save some textbox values into my worksheet so they can be reinitiated when userform is closed and re-opened.  This is what I have thus far..but clearly its wrong!


Basicaly, I have a combobox(procNamecombobox) that populates from column "A" on worksheet "DailyNumbers".  I just want the below textboxe.Values to save in the corresponding columns (B,C,D & E) next to each name, when its selected in the combobox.

```
  Private Sub procNamecombobox_Change()    

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim EmptyRow As Long

  Set ws = Sheets("DailyNumbers")
  EmptyRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  ' *** Check combobox selection ***
  If procNamecombobox.ListIndex > -1 Then

  ws.Range("B" & EmptyRow).Value = completeCount.Text
  ws.Range("C" & EmptyRow).Value = handledCount.Text
  ws.Range("D" & EmptyRow).Value = wipCount.Text
  ws.Range("E" & EmptyRow).Value = suspendCount.Text
  ws.Range("B2:B" & EmptyRow).Sort key1:=ws.Range("A1:A" & EmptyRow),  order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
  Else
 MsgBox "Please select your name"
 End If

  End Sub
```

Comment: you can also add code to your previous question by editing the question itself, you have the "edit" link at the bottom of your question.

Comment: As this question has an answer maybe combine the text from both questions (using _edit_) and delete the other question?  I'll start the ball rolling and vote for the other one to be closed.

Comment: is there a close button Im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following, it will search Column A for the Combobox value, if found it will update that row, if not found, it will populate the EmptyRow:

```
Private Sub procNamecombobox_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("DailyNumbers")
Dim EmptyRow As Long
Dim FoundVal As Range
EmptyRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
' *** Check combobox selection ***
    If procNamecombobox.ListIndex > -1 Then
        Set FoundVal = ws.Range("A1:A" & EmptyRow).Find(procNamecombobox.Value) 'find Combobox value in Column A
        If Not FoundVal Is Nothing Then 'if found
            ws.Range("B" & FoundVal.Row).Value = completeCount.Text 'use that row to populate cells
            ws.Range("C" & FoundVal.Row).Value = handledCount.Text
            ws.Range("D" & FoundVal.Row).Value = wipCount.Text
            ws.Range("E" & FoundVal.Row).Value = suspendCount.Text
        Else 'if not found use EmptyRow to populate Cells
            ws.Range("A" & EmptyRow).Value = procNamecombobox.Value
            ws.Range("B" & EmptyRow).Value = completeCount.Text
            ws.Range("C" & EmptyRow).Value = handledCount.Text
            ws.Range("D" & EmptyRow).Value = wipCount.Text
            ws.Range("E" & EmptyRow).Value = suspendCount.Text
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select your name"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @user3806255, please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks :)

Comment: So for some reason, when I select a name from the combobox (procNamecombobox) it moves row A1:F1 below 6 lines and doesn't save the textbox values?

Comment: @user3806255 Please try my updated answer... I believe it should do what you expect now.

Comment: Just one issue, it only add the amount after you select a name from the combobox.  The process would be (1) select your name (2) everything you process for that day gets counted and saved to the excel sheet.

Comment: @user3806255 all you have to do is not clear the value from the combobox when/after saving...

Comment: Got it to work, thank you very much! I have marked your answer